# How to check if the name is in a list that is recognized by its similar term in a predicate?

Tags: prolog

Suppose, I have a prolog predicate such as:

```
name(music,[jazz,blues,classical]).
```

and what I want is to check membership of say jazz and return me true if in music?

So far, I did this:

```
ismember(X,Y):-imember(X,name(Y,Z)),write(Z).
imember(X,[_|Tail]):-imember(X,Tail).
imember(X,[X|_]).
```

But it isn't working.

```
?- ismember(jazz,music).
false.
```

And it isn't writing the `write(Z)` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the visible part of the following fragment there is an error. Not only does your program fail, also the following generalization fails:

```
:- op(950, fy, *).
*(_).

ismember(X,Y):-
   imember(_/*X*/,name(_/*Y*/,Z)).

imember(X,[_|Tail]):-
   * imember(X,Tail).
imember(X,[_/*X*/|_]).

?- ismember(X, Y).
```

The generalization has been obtained by replacing some variables by `_`, and by removing one goal with `*`. It generalizes *as much as possible*. That is, any further generalization would make the goal succeed. And there is this nice property that holds in (pure, monotonic) Prolog:

If a generalization fails (for a specific query), then also the original program fails (for that same query).

That's the nice property that somehow establishes causality between a generalized fragment and the original program. If you want to remove the error, something in the generalized program has to be changed. Or conversely: If you make changes that still permit to get the generalization, then you have not fixed the error.

With this in mind,when searching for such a fragment, there is no need to "understand" the actual program. It suffices to guess and generalize mindlessly as long as this is possible.

Now, if we look at that generalization note that
the arguments of `ismember/2` are completely ignored!

Comment: And that went right over my head. I take it from your past answers that what you are saying is likely correct, but could you fill in the details for us mere mortals.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Anything missing?

Comment: Parts that I find to be glossed over, especially for someone new to Prolog are. 1. The inline comments `/*X*/` might be confused with the defined operator `:- op(950, fy, *).` 2. The use of `*` by itself; I have never seen that done before. 3. Examples showing the failure case of the original code, and how the modified code works in a more general sense.. After looking at this for a while I am now comfortable with it, but not adept enough with it to pass the ideas along.

Comment: The `*` as operator was mainly motivated to avoid warnings for singleton-variables ; and the `_/*X*/` is quite new - such a pity that there is no cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `name(Y,Z)` that you pass in `imember/2` predicate isn't a list. You could simply write:

```
ismember(X,Y):-name(Y,Z),imember(X,Z),write(Z).

imember(X,[_|Tail]):-imember(X,Tail).
imember(X,[X|_]).
```

Example:

```
?- ismember(jazz,music).
[jazz,blues,classical]
true.
```

Answer (score 0):

the ismember/2 predicate second parameter is a list , and you are not passing a list

here is a trace

```
[trace]  ?- ismember(jazz,music).
   Call: (8) ismember(jazz, music) ? creep
   Call: (9) imember(jazz, name(music, _6828)) ? creep
   Fail: (9) imember(jazz, name(music, _6828)) ? creep
   Fail: (8) ismember(jazz, music) ? creep
false.
```

@coder answer is a correct way

or you can simply use the member/2 predicate as follows:

first define your list in the database:

> `music([jazz,blues,classical]).`

now we have our music types list , next we write the rule

> `ismusicmember(X) :- music(L) , member(X,L),write(L).`

`music(L)` to assign the variable L to our music list

`member(X,L)`   the member/2 predicate check whether X is in the list or not

and running a query

```
?- ismusicmember(jazz).
[jazz,blues,classical]
true .
```

> a trace:

```
    [trace]  ?- ismusicmember(jazz).
   Call: (8) ismusicmember(jazz) ? creep
   Call: (9) music(_7376) ? creep
   Exit: (9) music([jazz, blues, classical]) ? creep
   Call: (9) lists:member(jazz, [jazz, blues, classical]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member(jazz, [jazz, blues, classical]) ? creep
   Call: (9) write([jazz, blues, classical]) ? creep
[jazz,blues,classical]
   Exit: (9) write([jazz, blues, classical]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) ismusicmember(jazz) ? creep
true .
```